# Java Mail Sender in Spring Boot Scheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, sender

i created a job that sending email automatic using java mail sender.

i want to ask about java mail sender performance using SMTP GMAIL, is it normal sending email with attachment (1 MB size) it takes 1-2 minute to sending 1 mail only.

is it possible to send mail in a second ? because i need to fast sending the mail to many customer email.

Comment: It would be good to have some more info on your environment and configuration. Where are you running your application? Localhost? Cloud Providers? OnPrimese? How's the SMTP configuration, is it IPv4, IPv6, Domain?

Comment: @MarcosBarbero for now in development im using localhost with SMTP Gmail, i see maybe thats the problem, next i want to try onprimese. any suggest about running my application on localhost , why tooks a long time to send it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Solved, when im implementing to OnPrimese it works fine, and sending the mail about 7 mail/minute, and some setting in app properties.
Thank You.